# How to lowercase field name in pdi (pentaho)?

Tags: javascript, pentaho-data-integration

I'm actually new to PDI and i need to do some extract from csv however sometimes field name are in lowercase or uppercase.
I know how to modify it for rows but don't know how to do it for fields names.

Does exist a step to do it? 
I tried ${fieldName}.lower(), lower(${fieldName}) in select value and javascript script  but without succes

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix is to right-click the list of column provided by the `CSV file input` to copy/paste it back and forth into Excel (or whatever).

If you also have 150 input files, the step which changes dynamically the column names (and other metadata like type) is called `Metadata Injection`, [Kettle doc](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection). The [Official doc](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0Y0/0K0/ETL_Metadata_Injection) gives details and examples.

Your specific case is covered in [BizCubed](https://wiki.bizcubed.com.au/xwiki/bin/view/Pentaho+Tutorial/Metadata+Injection). Download the sample near the end of the web page, unzip, load the ktr in PDI. You'll need to adapt the `Fields` step in the `MetaDataInjection` transformation. It is currently a `DataGrid` that you may change by a `Javascript` lowercase (or better a `String operation`), after having kept the first line only of your CSV (read with header NOT present, include the rownumber and `Filter` rownumber=1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a column name you can use the 'Select values' step.

There is a 'Rename to' option in the 'Select & Alter' tab as well as the 'Meta-data' tab that you can use to change a column name to whatever you want.

Comment: i have more than 150 field, do you have the syntax to do it? I still don't get how variable works in pentaho...

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no way to dynamically change all your column names.

Comment: You have 2 options really. 1. Make sure the csv headers are lowercase before it gets created. 2. Create the new column names yourself